# Azure Machine Learning REST API: why is the prediction included in the Sample Request?

Tags: azure, rest, schema, postman, azure-machine-learning-service

I followed Microsoft's tutorial on the German credit card risk model, step by step and without mistakes. The algorithm runs, it is deployed successfully, etc.

[image]

I am using the `Select Columns in Dataset` to select the columns to input, and I do the same to select the output columns.

I noticed that when I look at the `Request/Response` tab of the deployed model, the Sample Request includes *all* columns, ignoring the selection I provided. This includes the field to be predicted, which is column 21:

```
{
  "Inputs": {
    "input1": {
      "ColumnNames": [
        "Col1",
        "Col2",
        "Col3",
        "Col4",
        "Col5",
        "Col6",
        "Col7",
        "Col8",
        "Col9",
        "Col10",
        "Col11",
        "Col12",
        "Col13",
        "Col14",
        "Col15",
        "Col16",
        "Col17",
        "Col18",
        "Col19",
        "Col20",
        "Col21"
```

**The problem**: column 21 is the credit risk itself, so the API is expecting to receive that value. Instead, **that is the value that should be predicted!**

There clearly is a problem with the input schema, but how can I change that? How can I make sure that field is not requested by the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the input schema for the `Col21` field. The `Col21` field in the input data just adapt for the `Edit Metadata` module which requires the `Col21` data in the training stage.

You just fill an invalid value like `0` (`0` is an invalid classified value for risk) into `Col21` field, and then the web service will return a prediction classified value to replace the `Col21` value of your input data.

At here, I use the first data record of the sample data with the `Col21` value `0` for testing via the link of `Test` feature on portal, it works fine and return `1` for `Credit risk`

Fig 1. To click `Test` link to test for `Col21` with `0`

[image]

Fig 2. Use the first record of sample to test

[image]

Fig 3. The `Col21` value of `input1` is `0`, and the `Credit risk` value of `output1` is `1`

[image]